# In Google Analytics > User Explorer > Search For User

Tags: google-analytics

I am simply trying to search for a certain user based on their `Client Id`.  How Can I find a particular user like `129237576.1471287532` to view their 
`User Report`.

Secondly... how could I search all users for a pattern.  So instead of numbers.numbers - search numbers_numbers - so 129237576.1471287532 vs. 14756_7856.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you aren't able to search for a particular user. If you know the Client ID (ie. 11111111.22222222), then can't you just expand the table and do a Ctrl-F to search?

Regarding the second question, you are probably looking for a regex. I'm not sure where you would apply it in GA as you can't do a regex search since there's no Advanced search feature, but the regex you would use is

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Comment: You can expand the table/show up to 5000 rows... this GA has over 100,000 users/rows. So the Ctrl-F would not be an option for me.  Any other ideas?  I just cannot believe you can not search/filter/segment down to a certain user.

Answer (score 1):

Had to write a custom report based on all Users and then add the Dimension Drilldowns as User Identifier.